# ARM Cortex-M3: Store digits/string in memory

Tags: arm, cortex-m, thumb

I'm studying ARM Cortex-M3 with Thumb-2 instruction. I found some code that declares some data areas.

```
AREA RESET, DATA, READONLY
DULIEU  DCB &0F,&0D,&7,&0A
```

The first code is for declaring hexa number: FD7A. What does the'&' mean before each byte?

```
AREA Data1, DATA, READONLY
xau DCB "Hello, World", CR
```

So how can the string "Hello, World" be stored in a byte? And what is CR?

Comment: `CR` is almost certainly a macro for the number 10, the ASCII carriage return character, aka `\r`.  You'll probably find it defined higher up in your program, or in some include file.

Comment: @NateEldredge I see. So it means that the end of the string?

Comment: It isn't inherently an end-of-string marker.  More likely the programmer actually wants to emit a CR character after printing out the string, probably because they know it will make their terminal advance to a new line.

Comment: assembly is specific to the tool not the target, what specific tool are you using and what did the documentation say? post the part of the documentation you do not understand

Answer (score 1):

The [ARM assembler reference](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0068/b/Assembler-Reference/Expressions--literals--and-operators/Numeric-literals?lang=en) says that `&` is used as a prefix for hexadecimal numbers, just like `0x`.  So `&0F` is equivalent to `0x0F`, the number fifteen.

The [DCB directive](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0068/b/Directives-Reference/Data-definition-directives/DCB?lang=en) can be used to assemble multiple bytes, not just one.  So `DCB "Hello, World"` assembles the bytes `H`, `e`, `l`, `l`, `o`, etc, in sequence.

I don't think `CR` is defined by the assembler, but it is almost certainly a macro or equate for the number 10, the ASCII carriage return character, aka `\r`. You'll probably find it defined higher up in your program, or in some include file.

Comment: Thank you. So in the memory, characters such as `H`, `e`, `l`, etc will be encoded to ASCII code?

Comment: In the first code segment, can I know why there is `0` before `F`, `D`, `A` but not `7`?